# Is it possible to draw inside another drawing without going out in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, layers

Is it possible to draw inside an object without going outside? I want to scribble inside a circle without the drawing going outside of the circle....as for example in Photoshop, we can use clipping mask for that but I don't know about Inkscape. I am using Inkscape because my pc is low end and it doesn't have much memory

[image: This is how it happens]

This is how it happens

[image: "This is how I want it"]

This is how I want it

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape has no "draw inside" feature. However, you could use a clipping mask instead:

1. Draw some lines over a filled square, and group the square and the lines
2. Draw a circle on top
3. Select the group and the circle, and do *Object > Clip > Set*

[image]

Comment: Wow...even though draw inside fn isn't available I will use this....I have used clip but didn't know it can be done like this...thank you for the information 