# Keeping line segments inside rectangle

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to design a "grid" inside the rectangle with curve corners. I have drawn the rectangle, and then all the individual lines. Now the problem is clearly that the lines are going beyond the rectangle borders, and I want to avoid having to manually shorten them to fit the rectangle, as it's error-prone. I tried doing an intersection, but it's not working.[image]

Comment: Use a clipping mask?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to draw inside another drawing without going out in inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/145480/is-it-possible-to-draw-inside-another-drawing-without-going-out-in-inkscape)